# Object variable error in vba

Tags: vba

Trying to create a username/password validation form. getting the the following error "Object variable or with block variable not set" when i click login button i.e comamand1_click(). when i click debug it points to

```
> rs.ActiveConnection = conn
```

The code that i typed:

```
Dim a
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

Private Sub Command1_Click()
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = C:\VB Project\logindetails1.mdb"
conn.Open

If conn = Null Then
    MsgBox ("no db")
    End
End If

rs.ActiveConnection = conn
rs.Source = "select * from login"
rs.Open

rs.MoveFirst
While Not rs.EOF
If Text1.Text = rs.Fields("id") And Text2.Text = rs.Fields("password") Then
    a = 1
Else
    a = 0
End If
Wend
rs.Close
conn.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set conn = Nothing

If a = 1 Then
    MsgBox ("Login Successful!!")
Else
    MsgBox ("Invalid Details!!")
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Command2_Click()
Text1.Text = ""
Text2.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub Command3_Click()
End
End Sub
```

Comment: I've add the same error before and I did a replace in the module of `conn` to `sConn`, then back and it worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your rs (`ADODB.Recordset`) variable is `Nothing`.

You need to create the object.

```
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
```

Also, I think you'll need to use the `Set` keyword when setting the recordset's connection:

```
Set rs.ActiveConnection = conn
```

Comment: I did create the rs object at the very start of the code. Anyways, using set had no effect. Getting the same error on the same line.

Comment: @theIronGiant -- Creating rs isn't in your example. In your example, your "rs" variable will always be nothing (and even if it IS created somewhere at the start of your code, you are setting it to nothing at the end of your Command1_Click function, so it will be Nothing the next time that function is run). 

To test if it is really Nothing, you can do this: If rs Is Nothing Then MsgBox "rs is nothing"